# Are the predefined java LinkedLists Doubly linked?

Tags: java, linked-list

Since there are methods in the java API for LinkedList such as: remove the last node, and insert a node at a specific index in the LinkedList.. the LinkedList in the API would have to be a doubly linked list, right?

I tried making my own single linked list but from what I found it was impossible to insert a node in a specific index and it was impossible to remove the last node in the list. So if I wanted to do that, I should create my own doubly linked list?

Comment: You can definitely insert and remove last from a singly linked list.

Comment: can you show me code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`java.util.LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) javadoc clearly states

> Doubly-linked list implementation of the List and Deque interfaces.

You need to declare your variable as a `LinkedList` to see its methods, like [`removeLast()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#removeLast%28%29).

```
LinkedList<String> linkedList = new LinkedList<>();
... // add stuff
linkedList.removeLast(); // compiles

List<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
... // add stuff
list.removeLast(); // doesn't compile
```

Comment: Actually, `removeLast()` comes from `Deque` interface http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html#removeLast() Hence, you can also refer like `Deque<String> xxx = new LinkedList<String>(); xxx.removeLast();`